# why there are .dll or .py files

Tags: java, python, dll

I always have a question in my mind. When I look at the installation folder of a program, though the software is claimed to be written in Java, there are some dll / py or exe files in it.  This is completely weird to me as I used to believe a Java program should only contain .class files or jars. Can someone explain to me what is the reason behind this kind of setting?

---

I have read some tutorials about java native interface and is this the reason why there are dll and exe files?

Comment: Most probably yes. Java can call native code which doesn't make the application exactly "write once run everywhere" anymore. However, those executables might also just be "external" helper programs that aren't used by Java at all.

Comment: The software is written in Java, but is executed through an OS executable that starts the JVM (and does other things).

Comment: ask the software authors, there are plenty of different reasons for that!

Comment: Thanks for all answers! Is it common to develop a program with more than a language, like C++ with python? Won't this kind of development be more complicated than using just one language?

Comment: @HawiiHawii Python, or at least the main implementation - Cpython - is freely extensible with C and C++ and can also be embedded in other languages https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html. I don't know so much re: Java